# A Problem in Number Theory

Tags: number-theory, proof-verification

The problem is the following.

> Let $p$ be an odd prime. Prove that a belongs to the exponent $2$ modulo $p$
>   if and only if $a\equiv -1 \pmod p$.

**My proof:**

> For $\implies$, order of $a$ modulo $p$ is $2$. ($a$ belongs to the exponent $2$ modulo $p$), so $a^2\equiv 1 \pmod p$.
>
> Using the following lemma.
>   -Since $p$ is a prime, $x^2\equiv 1 \pmod p$ if and only if $x\equiv\pm 1 \pmod p$.
>  
> So, $a\equiv\pm1$.  
> But, if $a\equiv1 \pmod p$, then order of $a$
>   is $1$, which is contradiction to given in the problem.
>  So, $a\equiv -1 \pmod p$.
>
> For $\impliedby$, $a\equiv -1 \pmod p$.
>  $a^2\equiv 1 \pmod p$ So, order of $a$ is
>   $2$.

For somehow, my proof seems to be incomplete.
Is my proof not complete or not explicit or missing some parts?

Thanks.

Comment: I would add $x^2 - 1 = (x-1)(x+1)$.  Also the fact that $p$ is an odd prime never came up in your proof, which is... odd.

Comment: What does "belongs to the exponent 2 modulo p" mean?

Comment: @EnjoysMath yeah.. I should add it before saying $a≡\pm1$.

Comment: @dfeuer "a belongs to the exponent 2 modulo p" is a different way of saying "order of a modulo p is 2"

Comment: Thanks, @SimonComplex. I'd never seen that terminology before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modulo $2$, $x^2 - 1$ has only the one solution $1$.  But for $p \gt 2$ you always get two solutions described in the polynomial factorization $(x-1)(x+1) = 0 \pmod p \ $.  Notice that having exponent $2$ implies $x^2 - 1 = 0$ but the converse of that isn't necessarily true.  Putting the logic together, there is a solution $x$ with exponent two and $x^2 - 1 = 0 \pmod p$ iff ($x-1 = 0 $ *or* $x+1 = 0$) *and* $x$ has exponent two. Note that with boolean operators, $A \wedge (B + C) = (A \wedge B) + (A \wedge C)$.  For an or statement to evaluate to a true you need at least one of the operands to evaluate to true so since $x -1\neq 0$ ever, $x+1 = 0$ always.